I wanted to create custom dashboard interface in superset. Is it possible
Can I build custom dropdown filter in apache superset?
I'm building custom dashboards in my self project using Apache Superset.

I wanted to build dropdown filter based on users.
When I navigate & click particular option from the dropdown it has to redirect to specific user dashboard.

Could someone help me what will be steps of implementation and what kind of measures I should care while implementation by using Python and other front end tools using Flask API.

what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example

how to ask a good question:
how to ask
